# Is there an invective map $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $d^2 = f^{*}d^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, metric-spaces

Where $d^2((x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2))$ and $d^1(x,y)$ are the standard Euclidean distances in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$, respectively, and $f^{*}d^1((x_1,x_2), (y_1,y_2)) = d^{1}(f(x_1,x_2), f(y_1,y_2))$

---

I'm very sure such a map does not exist. As to the proof of that:

For $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$, where $x = (x_1, x_2)$ and $y = (y_1, y_2)$.
\begin{align*}
d^2 &= f^{*}d^1 \\
\sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2} &= |f(x) - f(y)| \\
(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2 &= (f(x) - f(y))^2 \\
{x_1}^2 - 2x_{1}y_{1} + {y_1}^2 + {x_2}^2 - 2x_{2}y_{2} + {y_2}^2 &= f(x)^2 - 2f(x)f(y) + f(y)^2
\end{align*}
As clearly $f(x)$ must be defined solely in terms of $x$ (I don't know a more formal way to say that), $f(x) = \sqrt{{x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2}$ but clearly this is not injective, so such an injective map $f$ cannot exist.

Does this prove that statement? If not, why not, and what direction should I be taking?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is good. To formally convert the algebra into the statement you want, consider what happens when $y=(0,0).$ [Note that it will not quite imply that $f(x)=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$, so you'll have to be a bit careful about how you conclude.]

Comment: If $(y_1, y_2) = (0,0)$, 
\begin{equation*} 
{x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2 = f(x)^2 - 2f(x)f(y) + f(y)^2 
\end{equation*}
but this doesn't go anywhere without the assumption that $f(x) = \sqrt{{x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2}$ (which is really what I'm trying to justify). Can you elaborate on your "$y = (0,0)$" hint?

Comment: @user372834: Since $y$ has been specified, $f(y)$ is a constant, maybe $a$. Therefore the RHS of what you've written is $(f(x)-a)^2$. [Note: you *cannot* now take the square root of both sides since $x=y$ does not imply that $\sqrt x = \sqrt y$. It's not "too" wrong, so you can still reason it.]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution:

Assume such an $f$ exists. First note that the map $f$ is an isometric embedding of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}$ i.e. injective an homeomorphic to its image. We note that $X:=\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ is connected and so $f(X)$ is also. However $$f(X) \subset (-\infty, f(0)) \cup (f(0), \infty)$$ and so $f(X)$ is disconnected, thus no such $f$ can exist.